# LaTex и ГОСТ 2.503-90 вставка страниц формата 1а 2а и т.д. в уже готовый документ

Tags: latex

Интересует вопрос по счётчикам.
Можно ли в уже готовый документ вставить страницы 10а, 10б, потом 18а,18б.

как это описано в ГОСТ 2.503-90. Цитата

> При добавлении нового  листа документа допускается присваивать ему
>   номер предыдущего  листа с добавлением очередной строчной буквы
>   например 3а,  при этом на заглавном листе изменяют количество страниц

Формат листов и место для вывода не номера листа не так важны в данный момент

Я начал писать команду, которая создаёт страницу и в этой странице переопределяет счётчик и заводит новый счётчик, и для вставки одного листа всё работает,  а вот  когда вызываешь  команду второй раз, он уже отрабатывает не корректно.

Вот,  что  я хочу получить в итоге [Скачать на DropBox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12354302/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82.pdf) (сделано  в `MS Word`)

Comment: можно вручную задать нумерацию конкретной страницы («3а») и переустановить счётчик для следующей страницы: http://s.arboreus.com/2007/07/latex_19.html

Comment: ну и, наверное, стоит обратить внимание на пакеты [eskd](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eskd) и [eskdx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eskdx). возможно, в них данная нумерация уже реализована.

Comment: к сожалению в данных пакетах такой возможности  нет (словом я пользуюсь пакетом eskdx) и всё было хорошо, пока не встала необходимость вставить несколько листов в готовый документ  в соответствии с ГОСТ.

Answer (score 1):

в пакете *babel*, в частях для русского и украинского языков, есть полезный макрос `\asbuk`, который действует подобно `\arabic` и `\roman`, возвращающим арабские и римские цифры, соответствующие переданному аргументу, и возвращает буквы кириллицы.

переработал код из этого ответа: [Intervening pages that do not add to page-count?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155326/79376)

получился вот такой пример:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% существенная часть:
\newcounter{mypagecount}
\setcounter{mypagecount}{0}
\newenvironment{interlude}{
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{mypagecount}{\value{page}}
  \addtocounter{mypagecount}{-1}
  \setcounter{page}{1}
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{mypagecount}\asbuk{page}}
  }{%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{page}{\value{mypagecount}}
  \stepcounter{page}
  }
% конец существенной части
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{section 1}
\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{interlude}
\section{section 1a}
\lipsum[5-15]
\end{interlude}

\section{section 2}
\lipsum[10-20]

\begin{interlude}
\section{section 2a}
\lipsum[5-15]
\end{interlude}

\section{section 3}
\lipsum[10-20]

\end{document}
```

вставки делаются с помощью окружения `interlude` (название произвольное, взято из примера по ссылке).

нумерация получившихся страниц: 1, 2, 3, 3а, 3б, 3в, 4, 5, 5а, 5б, 5в, 6, 7.

в оглавление именно такая нумерация и поступает.

### дополнение

предложенное выше решение хорошо «сработает», если вставки располагать в месте разрыва страниц (например, перед новой главой).

если же требуется сделать вставку в произвольном месте, например, между страницами `x` и `x+1`, так, чтобы абзац, «перетекающий» с конца страницы `x` на страницу `x+1`, продолжал так же «перетекать» после того, как мы сделаем «вставку» между страницами `x` и `x+1`, то следует «обернуть» «вставку» в вызов макроса `afterpage` (из одноимённого пакета):

```
\afterpage{
 \begin{interlude}
 текст ваставки
 \end{interlude}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую отпишусь, если получится, то  в eskdx сделаю patch с данным решением. Про пакет babel я знаю, меня интересовал механизм вставки страниц.

Comment: @АнтонБрюзгин, вероятно, чтобы «вставки» не нарушали по-страничную разбивку документа, ещё стоит добавить, например, [`\afterpage`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36880/79376).

Comment: Извиняюсь,  был в командировке, не мог попробовать. Сейчас всё сделал,  получилось спасибо за советы, осталось придумать как сказать LaTeX,  что количество страниц надо  увеличить,  а то он  вставленные страницы то не считает.

Comment: @АнтонБрюзгин, кстати, я [спрашивал на tex.se, как вставить `\afterpage` внутрь окружения](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334988/79376), но поленился дополнить ответ здесь подсказанным решением.

Comment: Да, спасибо,  я попробовал данное решение. Но основная проблема теперь это  увеличение количества страниц в документе. Если например вставить три страницы в документ  в котором уже есть 3 страницы,  а потом с помощью пакета lastpage вывести количество страниц \pageref{LastPage}, то получим количество равное трём,  а не шести страницам. Может Вы Александр и такой вопрос задавали  и знаете на него ответ. Заранее благодарен.